# Downloading file which has been uploaded in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am uploading file and showing its display name as where it is stored and its an anchor tag.

Below is the code:-

```
<input type="button" class="uploadButton" id="btnUploadPDF" value="Upload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dvFileUpload" />
                                            <a class="img-responsive" id="ImgSignedDoc" data-filename="" href="" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

The filename is coming in `anchor tag`. Here is how it looks

[image: Img]

Now what I want is, after uploading this file at a place, I want to download the file for reference on click of that anchor tag. How can I implement this in jquery. ASP.net will also do.

**EDIT**

The logic for storing file

```
function setImagesUploadedFile(JsonObject) {
for (i = 0; i < JsonObject.length; i++) {
    var obj = JsonObject[i].Filename;
    var obj2 = "ImgSignedDoc";
    var obj3 = JsonObject[i].FileType;
    var datafileName = JsonObject[0].ImageName;

    var ImgObj = parent.document.getElementById(obj2);
    ImgObj.innerText = SharedFilePath + obj;
    $(ImgObj).attr("data-filename", datafileName);
}
```

}

Comment: save the file path name to a variable in jQuery, then change the attribute href of the download button to that variable.

Comment: @Stender: can you give in description as what should I do and at what event ?

Comment: hard to do without anymore code - but the upload is working?

Comment: meaning, the file is stored on the server/localhost?

Comment: @Stender: yes the upload is working fine and its getting saved in folder also. Should I update the question with the code ?

Comment: for now file is stored in localhost

Comment: @Stender: Updated the question. have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could help you on your way - implement this in your setImagesUploadedFile function - or on it's success call or something.

```
 var b = document.getElementById("ImgSignedDoc");
 b.setAttribute("href", SharedFilePath + obj);
```

OR with jQuery

```
$('#ImgSignedDoc').attr('href', SharedFilePath + obj);
```

So entire function here :

```
function setImagesUploadedFile(JsonObject) {
    for (i = 0; i < JsonObject.length; i++) {
        var obj = JsonObject[i].Filename;
        var obj2 = "ImgSignedDoc";
        var obj3 = JsonObject[i].FileType;
        var datafileName = JsonObject[0].ImageName;

        var ImgObj = parent.document.getElementById(obj2);
        ImgObj.innerText = SharedFilePath + obj;
        $('#ImgSignedDoc').attr('href', SharedFilePath + obj);
        $(ImgObj).attr("data-filename", datafileName);
    }
}
```

Do you get any errors in the console?

EDIT

So after chatting, the solution was to use the text already set, and set it to attribute. meaning.

```
var filepath = e.innerText; 
$('#ImgSignedDoc').attr('href', filepath);
```

and the download button works now.

Comment: click is getting fired but file is not downloading

Comment: If forgot. I made the attribute on the upload button. It should of course be on the download load button

Comment: @VVVV Updated the answer

Comment: @VVVV  are your page reloading after/during upload?

Comment: no, i am not reloading the page. the thing is that outside `setImagesUploadedFile` i am not getting `SharedFilePath`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150820/discussion-between-vvvv-and-stender).

Comment: can u come on chat, i cracked it

Comment: Thanks Stender.. :)